Keyboard Shortcut CMD + Shift + R opens Multiple Apps and I can't figure out why
I have been trying to figure this issue out for a while now,
but by pressing CMD + Shift + R which should hot reload my Arc browser, my Macbook Pro decides to open up Adobe Acrobat, Brave Browser, Transmit and iTerm.
I have looked through the shortcuts of RayCast, Apple, have tried to use ShortcutDetective but I can't figure out where the shortcut comes from.
Anyone has an idea how to detect it and eliminate it?

Welcome to Ask Different. Which app has focus when you press Shift-Command-R? Which version of macOS is your device running?

Do you use any apps like Bunch or Moom that allow you to save "sets" of app windows?
